# RadSplitter Remove Borders not working

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik

I am working on an Asp .net project and i Am using RadSplitter to split me website. I want to remove the borders from the splitter. Here is my asp code below, i remove the borders but they are still appear. Can anyone help me please?

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="webbetv1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
    <html runat="server">
    <head >
    <style type="text/css">

    .RadSplitter .pane,  
.RadSplitter .paneHorizontal 
{ 
    border: 0px  !important; 
    padding: 0px !important;
}
        .style1
        {
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 33px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Put your JavaScript code here.
    </script>
    </head>
     <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <body>

    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" Runat="server">
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
    <div  style="height:800px; width: auto;">
        <telerik:RadSplitter ID="MainSplitter" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" ExpandMode="FullExpandItem" 
            Orientation="Horizontal" LiveResize="false" BorderSize="0" BorderWidth="0px"  BorderStyle="None" CssClass="pane"   >
            <telerik:RadPane ID="TopPane" runat="server" Height="120" MinHeight="85" MaxHeight="150" BorderWidth="0px"   
                Scrolling="none" CssClass="pane" >
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder3" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>

                <table class="style1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            sadasd</td>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </telerik:RadPane>
            <telerik:RadSplitBar ID="RadsplitbarTop" runat="server" CollapseMode="Forward" Height="100%" BorderWidth="0px" BorderStyle="None" />
            </telerik:RadSplitter>
            </div>
             </body>
            </form>

            </html>
```

[image: Here the image:]

Comment: Please replay or set the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
border: none;
```

to your `.pane` **css** class.

I had the same problem and I had to add that to the css class as well as setting `BorderStyle="None"` and `BorderSize="0"` . I'm working with a master page and I suspected that the property was being overwritten somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

No css should be necessary in order to remove the borders:
On the RadSplitter set:

```
PanesBorderSize="0" BorderWidth="0"
```

On the RadPane set:

```
BorderWidth="0"
```

Now that the image is visible, maybe you just want to hidden the RadSplitBar. In that case you can both remove it or just set `Visible="False"`.